# I want to get integer values from three text files using multiple threads and check if these are prime number if so store them in new file

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, structure, file-handling

The function used here is working but as i am sending each threads to do this job the threads are overdoing or doing noofthreads time because of the for loops used for them when creating. I am out of logic here what can i do so that after succesfully loading and checking the 1159999 values from multiple text files i want to store them in seperate text file.

`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    pthread_mutex_t lck;
    typedef struct{
    int start;
    int end;
    }Innerstruct;`

    struct data{
    FILE **fptr;
    Innerstruct *inner;
    int numberthreads;
    int totalno;
    };

    int primecount=0;//to store prime numbers count
    int nofiles=3;

    void countlines(int *count,FILE **fptr,int nofiles){ //counts the no of lines of cordinates from the text    file
    int i;
    *count = 0;
    for(i=0;i<nofiles;i++){
        fseek(fptr[i], 0, SEEK_SET);
        char line[256]; // buffer to store each line
          while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr[i])){
            if(strlen(line) > 1){ // only increment if line is not empty so that this doesn't count blank spaces            (*count)++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    }

     void *getstorecountprime(void *p){
    FILE *fptr4;
    fptr4 = fopen("PrimeNumber.txt","w");
    if(fptr4==NULL){
        printf("Error creating file");
    }
    struct data *d1 = p;
    int i,j,k,num,start,end;
    for(k=0;k<d1->numberthreads;k++){
        start= d1->inner[k].start;
        end = d1->inner[k].end;

        for(j=start;j<=end;j++){
        for(i=0;i<nofiles;i++){
            fseek(d1->fptr[i], j, SEEK_SET);
            fscanf(d1->fptr[i],"%d",&num);

             if(checkprime(num)){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lck);
            fprintf(fptr4,"%d\n",num);
            primecount++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lck);
              }
        }
      }
      }
    
    }

    void main(){
    //checking for any error on opening the files
    FILE *fptr1,*fptr2,*fptr3;
    // opening text files
    fptr1 = fopen("PrimeData1.txt","r");
    fptr2 = fopen("PrimeData2.txt","r");
    fptr3 = fopen("PrimeData3.txt","r");
    if(fptr1==NULL || fptr2==NULL || fptr3==NULL){
        printf("Could not open all files");
        exit(1);
    }

    pthread_mutex_init(&lck,NULL);
    FILE *fptr[] = {fptr1,fptr2,fptr3}; //array of file pointer
    int num_threads,sliceperthread,*numarray;
    int i;

    int totalcount = 0;//to store total numbers
    pthread_t *id;
    struct data d1;
    countlines(&totalcount,fptr,nofiles);//counts the no of lines from txt files
    numarray = malloc(totalcount*sizeof(int));//dma to store all datas in array

    printf("Enter how many threads do you want:");
    scanf("%d",&num_threads);


    id = malloc(num_threads*sizeof(pthread_t));//dma thread equal to the number of thread
    d1.inner = malloc(num_threads*sizeof(Innerstruct));//dma the inner structure containing 
                                                              start and end

    d1.fptr = malloc(nofiles*sizeof(FILE*));//dma the fptr as array of nofiles size
    sliceperthread = totalcount/num_threads;
    d1.fptr=fptr;//assigned the fptr of structure to array of file pointer created above
    d1.numberthreads=num_threads;\
    d1.totalno = totalcount;
    d1.inner[0].start = 0;
    d1.inner[0].end = sliceperthread;

    for(i=1;i<=num_threads;i++){
        d1.inner[i].start = d1.inner[i-1].end + 1;
        d1.inner[i].end = d1.inner[i-1].end + sliceperthread;
    }

    for(i=0;i<num_threads;i++){
        pthread_create(&id[i],NULL,getstorecountprime,&d1);
        pthread_join(id[i],NULL);
    }
    printf("%d",primecount);
    }



     int checkprime(int n){
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<=n/2;i++){
         if(n%i == 0){
        return 0;
         }else{
        return 1;
        }
    }
    }``
```

As you can see from the code that i tried using a nested structure for this process. I created a structure which will store file pointers array and another inner structure array having start and end so that this could be used for threads start and end point. So i used a for loop to create threads and assign them function sending the structure as parameter. I was expecting to get prime numbers in text file but because of the iteration the program just keeps on adding values to the file.

Comment: Please format/indent your code so that it's comprehensible.

Comment: Having the main thread call `pthread_create` and immediately call `pthread_join` on the created thread is no better (actually, slightly worse) than a normal, single-threaded program.

Comment: For the reason stated in the previous comment by someone else, I suggest that you call `pthread_join` only after creating all threads. In other words, I suggest that you move `pthread_join` outside the loop. However, this is only a performance issue and should not affect the correctness of your program.

Comment: You never increment the count in your function to count lines.

Answer (score 1):

At least these problems:

**No increment**

`(*count)++;` is lost in a comment. [@M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75435629/i-want-to-get-integer-values-from-three-text-files-using-multiple-threads-and-ch/75438412#comment133102210_75435629)

```
        if(strlen(line) > 1){ // only increment if line is not empty so that this doesn't count blank spaces            (*count)++;
        }
```

**Wrong `checkprime(int n)`**

Hopefully with uniform formatting it is easy to see the loop only iterates, at most, once and fails to return a value when `i < 2`.

```
int checkprime(int n) {
  int i;
  for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Save time, **auto format** code and **enable all compiler warnings** to rapidly identify various code problems.